# How to change the colour of a shaped clipping mask in GIMP

Tags: gimp, clipping-mask, layer-style

I made a file in Adobe Photoshop. Using a black coloured brush, I made a simple watercolour 'stamp', then clipped a solid colour layer mask to it, so that I can change the colour of the watercolour stamp to anything, at any time, non destructively.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Black and white watercolour stamp]

By showing the colour mask (and changing the colour) I can colour that watercolour stamp:

[image: Coloured watercolour mask]

Is there a way to do this in GIMP? I was able to open the PSD file in GIMP with all the layers, but cannot get the layer mask to work in GIMP so it changes the colour of the BW watercolour stamp.

The idea is to replicate the ability to create any shape and clip an image or colour to it, in GIMP, the way you can do it in Photoshop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIMP doesn't support that kind of layer clipping and isn't fully compatible with the PSD format, but there is a simple work around.

If you put the fill and smudge graphics within a layer group, you can set the blending mode of the filled layer to "Screen", and it will not affect layers below the group.

For example

[image]

Note that GIMP has its own native file format called XCF. Photoshop doesn't support XCF at all. GIMP only has very basic support for PSDs, just those with layers and layer masks really, i.e. no layer clipping, no layer effects, no adjustment layers, no Smart Objects, etc.